# Mock static method using power mockito returning a singleton class with dao instance in its constructor

Tags: java, database, powermockito

I have a singleton class which creates an instance of the dao class in its private constructor . This singleton class's instance is returned by a static method of a  service class .I am trying to mock the service class using power mockito.I get am getting the error mentioned below.

Below is the Singleton class:

```
public class UserFilterService extends AbstractService<UserFilterDAO,UserFilter {


    protected static UserFilterService instance = new UserFilterService();
    private UserFilterDAO UserFilterDAO;
    private UserFilterService() {
        userFilterDAO = new UserFilterDAOImpl();
    }
}
```

Below is the Service class:

```
public class UserServiceFactory {
    public static UserFilterService getUserFilterService() {
        return UserFilterService.instance;
    }
}
```

The dependencies i have in pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-mockito-release-full</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <classifier>full</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

The current test class i have

```
@Before
public  void before() {
    SuppressCode.suppressConstructor(UserFilterService.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(UserFilterService.class);
    UserFilterService mockAlarmFilterService = 
           EasyMock.createMock(UserFilterService.class);
    expect(UserFilterService.instance).andReturn(mockUserFilterService).anyTimes();
}

@Test
public void testgetuserFilterservice() {
    UserServiceFactorymocUserFactory=Mockito.mock(UserServiceFactory.class);

    when(mockEIBFactory.getuserFilterService()).thenReturn(mockUserFilterService);
}
```

This shows the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.mockito.mock.MockCreationSettings.isUsingConstructor()Z
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.InstantiatorProvider.getInstantiator(InstantiatorProvider.java:10)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:59)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
    at com.avaya.eib.dam.mgmt.EIBDataServiceFactoryTest.before(EIBDataServiceFactoryTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBefores(MethodRoadie.java:132)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:95)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:122)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:106)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: what do you want to test exactly? you want to test UserServiceFactory  class or UserFilterService class? or you want to test whether you are getting the same object when you call getUserFilterService multiple times so that you confirm singleton behaviour is working ?

Comment: I want to test UserServiceFactory class